# Data binding between two Polymer-elements

Tags: polymer

I have two polymer elements like

```
<moviegrep-element></moviegrep-element>
<custom-card-element></custom-card-element>
```

In moviegrep-element I got an array of objects called results. I want to use the results in my custom-card-element. How does it work?

Answer (score 4):

Use Polymers [data-binding](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html):

```
<moviegrep-element results="{{sharedResults}}"></moviegrep-element>
<custom-card-element results="{{sharedResults}}"></custom-card-element>
```

This assumes that both of your elements publish the *results* property as an attribute. Changes to the *results* property in one element are then propagated to the *results* property in the other element.

This also assumes that your elements are itself inside a Polymer element. Otherwise you need an [auto-binding template element](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding)